# Using QSS class on specific QListWidgetItem

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qlistwidgetitem

I would like to **highlight** (by defining a custom css) some items (`QListWidgetItem`) of a `QListWidgetItem`.

Since `QListWidgetItem` do not inherit from `QWidget`, there is no `setProperty` method which would have allowed me to define a css class.

What would an approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit from `QStyledItemDelegate` class and reimplement `paint` method, for example:

**Custom delegate class .H:**

```
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QPainter>

class SomeItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SomeItemDelegate(QObject *parent = 0){}
    ~SomeItemDelegate(){}
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;

signals:

public slots:
};
```

**Custom delegate class .CPP:**

```
void SomeItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{

    bool isSelected = option.state & QStyle::State_Selected;
    bool isHovered = option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver;
    bool hasFocus = option.state & QStyle::State_HasFocus;

    if(index.data(Qt::UserRole) == "custom") {
        if(isHovered)
            painter->fillRect(option.rect, QColor(0,184,255,40));
        if(isSelected)
            painter->fillRect(option.rect, QColor(0,184,255,20));
        if(!hasFocus)
            painter->fillRect(option.rect, QColor(144,222,255,5));
    }

    painter->save();
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    painter->drawText(option.rect, Qt::AlignLeft, index.data().toString());
    painter->restore();
}
```

**Some yours `QListWidget` logic:**

```
QListWidget *listW = new QListWidget(this);
QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem(tr("Custom Text"));
item->setData(Qt::UserRole, "custom");
QListWidgetItem *item2 = new QListWidgetItem(tr("Simple Text"));
listW->addItem(item);
listW->addItem(item2);

SomeItemDelegate *del = new SomeItemDelegate();
listW->setItemDelegate(del);
```